# Trying to create 1-1 redirects, exclude certain directories/files, and then redirect any other traffic to new website

Tags: htaccess

I'm stumped on how to achieve this. The 1-1 redirects work fine as well as the global redirect to send anything to the new page that isn't contained in the code. But when trying to exclude one (or multiple) files/directories it will always redirect to `https://example.com/homepage`

I ran this through an htaccess checker and when testing against `https://test.com/documents/test.pdf` it ends right at the exclude statement but on the actual server it does not.

Any ideas?

Use case:
`https://example.com/documents/test.pdf` should not be redirecting, but it does, and it ends up redirecting to `https://example.com/homepage`.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Exclude files / directories from redirects

RewriteRule ^(documents)($|/) - [L]

# Redirect specific files / pages to new locations

RedirectMatch 301 /page1.html https://example.com/new-page1.html
RedirectMatch 301 /dir1/page1.html https://example.com/random-new-page.html
RedirectMatch 301 /documents/awesome.pdf https://example.com/new-webpage-to-replacepdf.html

# Redirect anything else that isn't above to the homepage

RedirectMatch 301 / https://example.com/homepage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix `RewriteRule` and `RedirectMatch` like that.   You need to implement the redirects using another `RewriteRule` for it to work like you want.  A rewrite rule can't prevent a redirect match from working.   Instead your rules should be:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Exclude files / directories from redirects

RewriteRule ^(documents)($|/) - [L]

# Redirect specific files / pages to new locations

RewriteRule ^page1.html$ https://example.com/new-page1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dir1/page1.html$ https://example.com/random-new-page.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^documents/awesome.pdf$ https://example.com/new-webpage-to-replacepdf.html [R=301,L]

# Redirect anything else that isn't above to the homepage

RewriteRule .* https://example.com/homepage [R=301,L]
```

I also would't suggest using that last rule.  It isn't good user experience, or good for SEO to redirect everything to the home page.  It is better practice to use a rule to direct URL to their exact corresponding counterpart:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```